# Visual Studio sharepoint list as a database without Sharepoint Server

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed Visual studio. I want to create web tool which should use SharePoint List as a database. I should not install SharePoint Server, it is not approved for my team. To create a project which is related to Sharepoint Visual studio throwing a message to install Sharepoint server. Please provide some solution for this.

Comment: how do you want to access the sharepoint list, when you don't have sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have List without a SharePoint Environment. However, If you dont want to install SharePoint on premise but still want to use it SharePoint List, you can go for trail pack of Office 365 and create the SharePoint sites and create lists there. You can also use them in Visual Studio.